# How to redact texts in a pdf file in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, pdf, redaction

I am struggling to apply text redaction in a PDF file in a aws lambda function written in NodeJs. Here is a list of libraries that I have tried with no success:

[pdf-lib](https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib): This library almost fulfils all the requirements except that it doesn't redact the text permanently as part of its limitations https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib/issues/827

[PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js): To overcome the above limitation, tried to covert the pdf to an image, so the redaction black boxes are applied permanently. Example code here: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/node/pdf2png/pdf2png.js However, this lib is not reliable as this cannot extract contents from most pdfs during the process.

Finally, [Pdf2Pic](https://github.com/yakovmeister/pdf2image): This library helps to overcome the limitation of the first library (pdf-lib) by the converting the pdf into images. But this library internally uses two non node based libraries ([graphicsmagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) and [ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/)) which I am trying to avoid.

Is there a nodejs based solution that can be used to apply redaction permanently on a pdf file or any solution that can be used to covert a pdf to images to overcome limitation of pdf-lib.

Comment: 6 months later, I still need the same answer. Do you have any news to share?

Comment: https://pdfbox.apache.org/ was the solution for me.